# Exchange Web Service (EWS) call fails under ASP.NET but not a console application

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm getting an error when I attempt to connect to Exchange Web Services via ASP.NET.

The following code works if I call it via a console application but the very same code fails when executed on a ASP.NET web forms page. Just as a side note, I am using my own credentials throughout this entire code sample.

*"When making a request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids."*

I thought I might be able to fix the issue by specifying an impersonated user.

```
exchangeservice.ImpersonatedUserId = 
    new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "email@domain.com");
```

But then I get a different error.

*"The account does not have permission to impersonate the requested user."*

The App Pool that the web application is running under is also my own account (same as the console application) so I have no idea what might be causing this issue.

I am using .NET framework 3.5.

Here is the code in full.

```
var exchangeservice =
                        new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
                        {
                            Timeout = 10000
                        };

 var credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pass", "domain");


exchangeservice.AutodiscoverUrl("email@domain.com")

FolderId rootFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);

var folderView = new FolderView(100)
            {
                Traversal = FolderTraversal.Shallow
            };

            FindFoldersResults findFoldersResults =
                service.FindFolders(rootFolderId, folderView);
```

Comment: Does the url that gets set against the service match when you run it under both environments?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the console application works if executed on the same web server?  eg is there something blocking connectivity between your web server and the exchange server?

Comment: This is my local development box so I can't see any connectivity issues blocking me.

Comment: @RichAndrews I'm not specifying the URL anywhere, the AutodiscoverUrl() is doing all of that for me.

Comment: I realise that, however if you put a breakpoint after the autodiscover you can see the "discovered" url as a property within the service. I had some issues with autodiscover where in some environments it was resolving to an incorrect proxy. It may not help but it's always a good idea to check it's connecting you to the same endpoint

Comment: Thanks for your help @RichAndrews. The AutoDiscoverUrl is {https://webmail.domain.com.au/ews/exchange.asmx}. This is the correct URL.

Comment: It may be a typo but you are not actually using the "credential" variable anywhere.  You need to set the credentials on the "service" object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried setting the credential against the service directly?

```
this.exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "pass");

this.exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl("username", this.RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

and using this as the validation callback..

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Redirections the URL validation callback.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="redirectionUrl">The redirection URL.</param>
    /// <returns>true if https</returns>
    private bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
    {
        // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
        var result = false;

        var redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

        // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
        // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
        // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
        if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
        {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the credentials and see whether the user has enough permission to impersonate. Checking the EWS throttling policies and provide right permission would solve the issue.